# Should we say Leelou Nishmat ou Leelou Nishmata for a deceased woman?

Tags: halacha, hebrew

Should we say Leelou Nishmat or Leelou Nishmata for a deceased woman?

I heard a Rabbi saying Leelou Nishmata but it seems quite uncommon. What should we say?

Comment: What are you trying to say? נשמת means 'soul of' and נשמתה means 'her soul'. I don't know what you want to say...

Comment: @DoubleAA Does that edit help? ....far22 is *probably* discussing the אל מלא prayer, but since I'm not 100% sure I wouldn't edit that in.....fae22, if that's what you meant, please [edit] that in. Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about the אל מלא prayer? Please [edit] that in if that's your intent. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

נשמת applies to both Masc. and fem. The word here is the possessive form / singular. The plural, incidentally would be נשמות as the word נשמה is fem. and gets the fem. ending. The plural form applies to the possessive word, in this case, נשמה and not the person or people who have the נשמ whether they are men or women. The blessing and more specifically the phrase you refer to is addressing the נשמה which is the same word used for men or women.

In your question, it is a bit unclear if your rabbi ended the phrase there or not. If yes, then what was said is correct as s/he was saying "For the rising of **her** נשמה" thus becoming נשמתה. If the rabbi included the person's name, then this would be incorrect.

Comment: How do you know what the rabbi was trying to say such that s/he was wrong?